# Windows Server 2008 r2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, options

I am using VMware ESX 3.5.  I installed my first Win Server 2008 R2.  I could select which version to install (Full Installation or Server Core)

Now when I am installing a new copy, it is not prompting to select a version. I wanted to select "Server core" but when I click on Install Now it goes straight away to "Accept License Term", then -- Next "Custom (Advanced) -- Next select the hard drive next "Windows Installing"

Can I have your advice? I have tried so many times; deleting and reinstalling, nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

if I remember this correctly I have seen this issue as well and my workaround was:

1) Setup a new VM and select Custom -> Vm name -> Storage -> VM Ver 8 -> Win Server R2 64 bit -> and finish the wizard

2) Mount the ISO file and boot - this time you should be asked if you want to install just the core

Alternatively just install the core and upgrade to Full as described here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/server_core/archive/2009/10/14/upgrading-windows-server-2008-r2-without-media.aspx

Comment: Hi TomEus this link doesn't reflect on my need Thanks anyway. basically when you install your Server OS you be prompted to select your Option